# How to format Procedures for complex searches

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So I am trying to create a way for users to search through data on my SQL Database.  Right now I've been getting away with using a single view using a lot of Joins:

```
CREATE VIEW PartsData AS
SELECT
    p.part_id                  AS [Part_ID],
    p.part_number              AS [Part_Number], 
    p.part_description         AS [Description], 
    p.information              AS [Information], 
    m.manufacturer_name        AS [Manufacturer], 
    ca.category_description    AS [Category], 
    su.subcategory_description AS [Subcategory],
    cu.currency_type           AS [Currency], 
    pl.cost_per_unit           AS [Price], 
    pl.discount_percentage     AS [Discount]
FROM         
    dbo.parts          AS P  INNER JOIN
    dbo.subcategories  AS su ON p.subcategory_id = su.subcategory_id INNER JOIN
    dbo.price_logs     AS pl ON p.part_id = pl.part_id AND pl.log_date = (SELECT MAX(log_date) FROM price_logs WHERE part_id = pl.part_id) INNER JOIN
    dbo.manufacturers  AS m  ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id INNER JOIN
    dbo.categories     AS ca ON su.category_id = ca.category_id INNER JOIN
    dbo.currencies     AS cu ON pl.currency_id = cu.currency_id
GO
```

And a rather crude 'kitchen sink' stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PartSearch(
    @PartID       INT          = NULL,
    @PartNum      VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Description  VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @Information  VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @Supplier     VARCHAR(75)  = NULL,
    @Manufacturer VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Category     VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Subcategory  VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @JobNum       VARCHAR(20)  = NULL
) AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        SELECT DISTINCT * FROM PartsData WHERE 1=1'
        + CASE WHEN @PartID IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Part_ID] = @PartID' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @PartNum IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Part_Number] LIKE @PartNum' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Description IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Description] LIKE @Description' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Information IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Information] LIKE @Information' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Supplier IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Supplier] LIKE @Supplier' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Manufacturer IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Manufacturer] LIKE @Manufacturer' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Category IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Category] LIKE @Category' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @Subcategory IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Subcategory] LIKE @Subcategory' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @JobNum IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND [Part_ID] IN (SELECT jp.part_id FROM job_parts AS jp INNER JOIN jobs AS j ON jp.job_id = j.job_id WHERE j.job_number = '''
         + @JobNum + ''')' ELSE N'' END

    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        @PartID       INT,
        @PartNum      VARCHAR(50),
        @Description  VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Information  VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Supplier     VARCHAR(75),
        @Manufacturer VARCHAR(50),
        @Category     VARCHAR(50),
        @Subcategory  VARCHAR(50)';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @params,
        @PartID,
        @PartNum,
        @Description,
        @Information,
        @Supplier,
        @Manufacturer,
        @Category,
        @Subcategory
END
GO
```

However this doesn't exactly work all that well for me anymore.  I'm at the point where I need to add more tables to the view, and more searches to the kitchen sink, and the 'default' table is just a mess of endless repeat entries that makes the whole thing look a mess.

This is essentially what I need to do:

1. Have a default View that shows a clean table, where each single Part Number is only shown once.
2. Be able to have one (or more) stored procedures that let me look through all the entries that could be on the table (including the repeat ones I don't want shown) in order to show specific search data.
3. Have it set up in a way where I could expand on it further in the future without it being a gigantic headache.

To give an example of what I want, I'll give you a small example data set.

```
Part Number        | Job Number        |  Price
AA.445               P0001                $100.00
AA.445               P0002                $100.00
AB.123               P0001                $75.00
AB.123               P0001                $50.00
AC.999               P0002                $25.00
```

I'd want the default table to appear as follows:

```
Part Number        | Job Number        |  Price
AA.445               P0002                $100.00
AB.123               P0001                $50.00
AC.999               P0002                $25.00
```

If I were to search by all parts for the `P0002` Job Number, I'd want the table to appear like so:

```
Part Number        | Job Number        |  Price
AA.445               P0002                $100.00
AC.999               P0002                $25.00
```

The sample size is probably too small to get across what I am trying to do.  Hopefully I've conveyed what it is I am trying to do though.

Now I am not asking someone to give me a full on SQL setup for all of this, but I am not sure how I am suppose to be formatting something like this, or even where to get started with giving this a better setup.  That's mainly what I am looking for a little bit of help on.

Comment: To get better help, you should post the table and index definitions for the tables in the view, and some example query plans when things are slow. There's quite a bit going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing... Nice job! Most people make a complete mess of this sort of thing. What you have is actually impressive.

There are a few things that you can do to make life a little easier.

1) lose the view. It's an unnecessary layer of abstraction at best and a good way to trick the optimizer into a bad plan at worst.

2) add a "@DeBug" parameter that allows you the option to print the generated sql rather than executing it. You'll be glad you have it the next time you need to track down an odd-ball error caused by a misplaced comma in a sea of red dynamic text. (I recommend this for all dynamic sql)

3) dynamic sql can end up being fairly complex and difficult to debug. Do yourself (and anyone else who may need to alter this proc in the future) and format the code so that the @DeBug output is properly formatted and easy to read.

So... Based on the above, here's how I'd do it... (Note that my own formatting preferences are reflected to some degree... You should change based on your own standards.)

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PartSearch
/* ==============================================================================
2018-11-26 Your Name,  Created for blah blah blah...
============================================================================== */
/* sample execution... makes debugging dynamic SQL MUCH easier.
EXEC dbo.PartSearch 
    @PartID       = 3333,
    @PartNum      = 'AB.123',
    @Description  = NULL,
    @Information  = NULL,
    @Supplier     = NULL,
    @Manufacturer = NULL,
    @Category     = NULL,
    @Subcategory  = NULL,
    @JobNum       = NULL,
    @DeBug        = 1;
*/

    @PartID       INT          = NULL,
    @PartNum      VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Description  VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @Information  VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    --@Supplier     VARCHAR(75)  = NULL,    -- column not in view...
    @Manufacturer VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Category     VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Subcategory  VARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @JobNum       VARCHAR(20)  = NULL,
    @DeBug        BIT          = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT(N'
    SELECT
        P.part_id AS [Part_ID],
        P.part_number AS [Part_Number],
        P.part_description AS [Description],
        P.information AS [Information],
        m.manufacturer_name AS [Manufacturer],
        ca.category_description AS [Category],
        su.subcategory_description AS [Subcategory],
        cu.currency_type AS [Currency],
        xpl.[Price],
        xpl.[Discount]
    FROM
        dbo.parts AS P
        JOIN dbo.subcategories AS su
            ON P.subcategory_id = su.subcategory_id
        JOIN dbo.manufacturers AS m
            ON P.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
        JOIN dbo.categories AS ca
            ON su.category_id = ca.category_id
        JOIN dbo.currencies AS cu
            ON pl.currency_id = cu.currency_id
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP (1)
                pl.cost_per_unit AS [Price],
                pl.discount_percentage AS [Discount]
            FROM 
                dbo.price_logs AS pl
            WHERE 
                P.part_id = pl.part_id
            ORDER BY
                pl.log_date DESC
            ) xpl
    WHERE 1 = 1',
        CASE WHEN @PartID IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N' 
        AND P.part_id = @PartID' 
        END,
        CASE WHEN @PartNum IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'
        AND P.part_number LIKE @PartNum'
        END,
        CASE WHEN @Description IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'
        AND P.part_description LIKE @Description' 
        END,
        CASE WHEN @Information IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N' 
        AND P.information LIKE @Information'
        END,
        --CASE WHEN @Supplier IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'  -- column not in view...
        --AND ?.Supplier LIKE @Supplier'
        --END,
        CASE WHEN @Manufacturer IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'
        AND m.manufacturer_name LIKE @Manufacturer'
        END,
        CASE WHEN @Category IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'
        AND ca.category_description LIKE @Category'
        END,
        CASE WHEN @Subcategory IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'
        AND su.subcategory_description LIKE @Subcategory'
        END,
        CASE WHEN @JobNum IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE N'
        AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM 
                        dbo.job_parts AS jp 
                        JOIN dbo.jobs AS j 
                            ON jp.job_id = j.job_id 
                    WHERE
                        P.part_id =  jp.part_id 
                        j.job_number = @JobNum
                    )'
        END,
        N';');

    IF @DeBug = 1
    BEGIN 
        PRINT(@sql);
    END;
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @params,
            @PartID,
            @PartNum,
            @Description,
            @Information,
            @Supplier,
            @Manufacturer,
            @Category,
            @Subcategory;
    END;
END;
GO
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any follow up questions...

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I talked with a friend of mine over the weekend about this problem I was having (he's been doing DB work for a while) and he suggested that I change the Search from a Stored Procedure to a Function to start with.  Would I still be able to apply your answer to a function?

Comment: @Skitzafreak - I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that your friend was basing his suggestion on the fact that you're currently using a view. In a sense, a table valued function can be used like a "view with parameters". The problem is that a function isn't well suited to this problem.

This kind of "kitchen sink" query has several possible solutions. 1) dynamic sql 2) control flow queries 3) optional parameters...

2) "control flow" is where you have a series of IF blocks, each with it's own version of the query based on unique combos of parameters...

Comment: For the sake of brevity... 99.9% of the time it's  bad option. 

3) "optional parameters"... `code`WHERE (t.Column = @parameter OR @parameter is null)`code`. This can be an excellent option but it suffers from the fact that the optimizer will always choose a scan rather than a seek. To fix the problem, we need to add  "OPTION(RECOMPILE)" to the query. The recompilation allows the optimizer to incorporate the parameter values into the execution plan, allowing it to choose a seek operation when appropriate. The down side is that you have to suffer a recompilation with every execution.

Comment: 1) parameterized dynamic sql... As long as to mitigate against the possibility of SQL Injection, it's the best of all worlds. The optimizer will compile a separate, reusable, plan for each unique combination it encounters. So, if the  same set of parameters is used "most of the time" the plan for that set will remain in cache and will be reusable.

Comment: So... Why is a function a bad idea here? a) You cannot use dynamic sql in a function. It's simply not allowed... or more precisely... The "EXECUTE" command isn't allowed in functions. b) You cannot include OPTION(RECOMPILE) in functions. Yes, you can use it in the outer/referencing query but no one will ever do it and performance will suffer horribly as a result. c) Considering a & b, they aren't the right tool for tackling "kitchen sink problems.

Comment: d) In this case there is no benefit over using your existing view. Looking at your OP code, I don't see anything that would prevent it being "in-lined" allowing the outer query filters to be pushed down to view. e) Even if a function would work, it would still be an unnecessary layer of abstraction, just like the current view.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.  I wish I could credit you with two answers :P

Comment: @Skitzafreak - Ha! Thank you for the kind feedback and sorry for the long winded explanation (and the crappy comment formatting). Also, just because I "think" I know why your friend made the function suggestion, doesn't mean I know with absolute certainty... If your friend can supply you with code that competes with the "parameterized dynamic sql using the base tables" approach above, please come back and post the code. I'd be interested in seeing what kind of tricks he has up his sleeve. :)